# Managing click event in DBGrid component

Tags: delphi

I'm facing to a problem by handling the click event on a DBGrid component. I know that this event is not exposed for this component, so I'm using the 'OnCellClick' event in order to do some actions when I click on a row of the DBGrid.

An other point is that, after filling my DBGrid (which is linked to a TkbmMemTable), I do a `memTable.First` in order to see the first element in the grid. The problem is that I can't trigger the onCellClick event for the first line. Indeed, when I click on the first line it triggers the double click event.

Answer (score 0):

You can make protected OnClick visible by derive an own component or declaring a (Hack)Class in the same Unit using your Grid, and assigning your event by an cast. But I'm not sure if this will deliver the desired result because the event will not be fired if you are clicking in and existing Editor of the grid, which will be kept if you are clicking in an other Row and the same column, so you will have to add OnCellClick or click into another column. I can't reproduce the firing of the double click event.

```
type
THackGrid=Class(TDBGrid);

procedure TForm5.MyEvent(Sender: TObject);
begin
   MyDataset.First;
end;

procedure TForm5.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  THackGrid(DBGrid1).OnClick := MyEvent;
end;
```

Comment: You tried it with the mentioned additional handling for OnCellClick needed for catching the event in the InplaceEditor?